# Screen freezes with no error from time to time when dismissing view in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I am having some troubles with: The screen freezing from time to time when Dismissing the ViewController displaying a picture over the current context.

May someone provide me some insights on how to fix this problem?

I tried using the pause button to examine the main thread but didn't find any unusual things.

[image: Snapshot of what is happening when screen freezes]

A sample of my codes is found below:

```
import UIKit

class ViewControllerCell: UICollectionViewCell {

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    backgroundColor = UIColor.white

    addSubview(showPhotoButton)

    showPhotoButton.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor, constant: 200).isActive = true
    showPhotoButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 160).isActive = true
    showPhotoButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
    showPhotoButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 70).isActive = true

}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}


lazy var showPhotoButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    button.setTitle("Show", for: .normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(showSale), for: .touchUpInside)
    button.setTitleColor(UIColor(r: 120, g: 80, b: 255), for: .normal)
    return button
}()


@objc func showSale() {
    let popupViewController = SalePopupViewController()
    popupViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
    popupViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.crossDissolve
    window!.rootViewController?.present(PopupViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

SalePopupViewController:

```
import UIKit

class SalePopupViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 0.60)
    view.isOpaque = false

    view.addSubview(rebateImage)
    view.addSubview(dismissButton)

    dismissButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
    dismissButton.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    dismissButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    dismissButton.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true

    rebateImage.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    rebateImage.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor, constant: -35).isActive = true
    rebateImage.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 290).isActive = true
    rebateImage.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1).isActive = true


}

let dismissButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(dismissPopup), for: .touchUpInside)
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return button
}()

let rebateImage: UIImageView = {
    let image = UIImageView()
    image.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    image.layer.masksToBounds = false
    image.layer.cornerRadius = 2
    image.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    image.clipsToBounds = true
    image.image = UIImage(named: "SaleCostco")
    return image
}()
@objc func dismissPopup() {
    weak var weakself = self

    weakself?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: { print("dismissing")})






       }

    }

}
```

Comment: in `dismissPopup` use `self.dismiss` directly

Comment: Tried that already, then I was recommended to use weak self, but neither fixes the problem.

Comment: whats the difference between PopupViewController  and SalePopupViewController ?

Comment: I updated the code above to SalePopupViewController!

Comment: post code viewcontroller in ViewControllerCell was shown

Answer (score 1):

First thing is why are you presenting the popup from `window!.rootViewController?` instead of the view controller that you you're calling it from? Just use `present(PopupViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)` instead.

Second thing is the weakself thing is completely unnecessary, as there is no way that self is released from memory but your dismiss button still exist, therefore it can hold a strong reference to self, making it weak makes no difference at all.

**Edit**

So I didn't see that ViewControllerCell is a collection view cell. 
Now the solution is different: You have a few options, 1. pass the viewController reference to each cell when you're doing the cell for item at indexPath function

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, 
  cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell{
if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier identifier: String) as? ViewControllerCell {
//do your thing here
 cell.parentViewController = self
```

}
}

and of course you have to set up a public var in the collectionViewCell

```
var parentViewController: UIViewController!
// you can also use the viewController subclass name that you created
```

//. if you want to use specific functions. If only present then you're good

And finally where you present you use parentViewController.present(....)

Comment: (1) I'm using window!.rootViewController? because the viewcontrollercell doesn't have "present".

(2) The second thing, I agree with you. I was just suggested to do so in a previous post and decided to see if it there is something wrong with the logic.